# Ubuntu wrong clock time (universal and local)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, clock

Local time and universal time are wrong. They are shifted to -2 hours to the real time.
Setting the timezone didn't solve because the universal time is wrong.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I have a **dual boot with Archlinux** (NOT windows).

EDIT:
After setting UTC on rcS file to "no" and **REBOOTED** also Ubuntu started to show the right time.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Check the bios clock. It may have gotten off, that could be caused by a dead battery on the motherboard.

Comment: The question is how can I fix the problem. I'm in Italy and I should have Europe/Rome localtime (+2:00) but I have to set Europe/Moscow (+4:00) for having the correct time.
The fact is that on Archlinux the clock is right. Why Ubuntu has this problem? (already tried to set UTC boh on "yes" and "no" in rcS file but didn't solve)

Answer (score 2):

The BIOS clock is incorrectly storing the local time, which isn't what is normally done on Unix/Linux (but is on Windows).

Your Arch Linux is set to store time in local time instead of UTC/GMT for some reason therefore when you reboot into Ubuntu, which is configured (correctly) to expect the BIOS clock to be storing UTC/GMT time, it's actually two hours off.

I haven't got Arch Linux in front of me, but I think it should go something similar to the following:

Set Arch to use UTC/GMT time:

```
# timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
```

Set the correct time:

```
# timedatectl set-time <insert UTC/GMT time here>
```

Reboot (maybe)